# Using PyQGIS, how do you project a shapefile from EPSG:4326 to 3857?

Tags: pyqgis, coordinate-system

I downloaded a few shapefiles but they're in EPSG:4326 and I need them in EPSG:3857. Is there a way to convert/save these files using PyQGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: In order to change the projection of your layer you could just use the option « save as » and select a new projection.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *Reproject Layer* algorithm from the processing toolbox.

Let's assume you have a *cities.shp* in a folder named *testing*, and you want to create a new file *cities_prj.shp* that is transformed into EPSG:3857, then this would do it:

```
import processing

processing.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer", r"D:\testing\cities.shp", "epsg:3856", r"D:\testing\cities_prj.shp")
```

Comment: @Complete_GIS_noob, if this answer solved your problem then please consider upvoting and accepting it by clicking the greyed out tick next to this answer. This could help other people with the same issues.